# pgadmin: create tablespace in windows folder

Tags: postgresql, tablespace

I am trying to create a tablespace in a Windows folder, but nothing seems to be working.
I am doing so with pgadmin.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE test
LOCATION 'C:\test'

This gives me error: 
ERROR:  tablespace location must be an absolute path 
SQL state: 42P17
```

I have tried writing the location differently:

```
'C:/test'
'C:\\test'
'C://test'
```

But nothing fixes it.

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to verify, which you have not made clear:

1. Is your database running on a Windows Server?
2. Have you actually already created the folder?

Both of theses are necessary in your case. A tablespace is not created so much as it is assigned. The create only creates the Postgres internal definition not the physical implementation. From the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtablespace.html)

> The location must be an existing, empty directory that is owned by the
> PostgreSQL operating system user. All objects subsequently created
> within the tablespace will be stored in files underneath this
> directory. The location must not be on removable or transient storage,
> as the cluster might fail to function if the tablespace is missing or
> lost.